# Formatting the code from IT to match Power Query / Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery

Could someone please confirm what code language is it and how do I edit it to fit with Power BI function to import data from SQL Database please?

Got this from IT person but when I try to paste it into Power Query it gives error messages.

```
SELECT distinct  Z.Territory , (z.AccountNumber          )  as AccountNumber , (a.AccountType                     ) as AccountType , (z.CompanyName                        ) as CompanyName , (z.AccountNumber        ) as AccountNumber , (z.CompanyName        ) as CompanyName , z.SubscriptionReference               ,z.SubscriptionID , (isnull(z.serialnumber,r.SerialNumber)             ) as SerialNumber ,case when (rpc.billingperiodalignment) =  'AlignToCharge' then (z.product) else  isnull(r.ProductDescription,z.product) end as Description  , (r.ProductVersion                                                      ) as ProductVersion , (r.CoverExpiryDate                           ) as CoverExpiryDate , (z.SubscriptionStatus                       ) as  SubscriptionStatus ,z.SubscriptionVersion 
--, MAX(z.RenewalTerm)             AS RenewalTerm , (z.[SubscriptionTermType]) as [SubscriptionTermType] , (case when z.[UnitofMeasure] = 'Desktop Users' then z.[Quantity] end) as 'Desktop Users' , (z.billingperiod                                              ) as BillingPeriod ,(rpc.BillingPeriodAlignment) BillingPeriodAlignment ,(z.[ContractEffectiveDate]) as  ContractEffectiveDate ,(z.TermEndDate) as  TermEndDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's SQL, but it's invalid, so you'll need to get it fixed.  It looks like it got cut off.  When it's valid you should be able to paste it into a [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16) query window and test it.

To use it in Power Query use [Value.NativeQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/value-nativequery), like this;

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("localhost", "adventureworks2017"),
    Query = "
    select * 
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    ",
    Data = Value.NativeQuery(Source, Query, null, [EnableFolding=true])
in
    Data
```